# Change values in df to 0 = FALSE, 1 = TRUE, 2 = TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing 0, 1 and 2s.
My goal is to switch those values so instead it shows FALSE for 0 and TRUE for 1 or 2.

I tried dplyr `case_when()` but it did not deliver the hoped for result.

```
test <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                "Primary" = c(0,0,2,1),
               "Secondary" = c(1,0,1,2),
               "Tertiary" = c(2,1,0,0))

test <- case_when(
 test$Primary == 0 ~ "FALSE",
 test$Primary != 0 ~ "TRUE",
 test$Secondary == 0 ~ "FALSE",
 test$Secondary != 0 ~ "TRUE",
 test$Secretory == 0 ~ "FALSE",
 test$Secretory != 0 ~ "TRUE",
 test$Tertiary == 0 ~ "FALSE",
 test$Tertiary != 0 ~ "TRUE")
```

The code above gave me one character vector with all results in one line but I would like to have the df structure to be maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_if` to change numeric columns to their logical equivalents:

```
test %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,as.logical)
  ID Primary Secondary Tertiary
1  A   FALSE      TRUE     TRUE
2  B   FALSE     FALSE     TRUE
3  C    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE
4  D    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE
```

Comment: As a dplyr fan this is the answer I longed for. Thanks a lot for the quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy in base R:

```
test[,-1] <- lapply(test[,-1], as.logical)
```

By default, 0 corresponds to FALSE, and all other values to TRUE, so `as.logical` does it for you. Probably it is easy to do it with dplyr as well, you definitely don't need that many lines in `case_when´.

Answer (score 1):

In base `R` one could do:

```
test[-1] <- test[-1] > 0
test
#   ID Primary Secondary Tertiary
# 1  A   FALSE      TRUE     TRUE
# 2  B   FALSE     FALSE     TRUE
# 3  C    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE
# 4  D    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE
```

If you insist on `dplyr` + `case_when` you could do:

```
test[-1] <- 
  test %>%
  select(-"ID") %>%
  mutate_all(
    funs(
      case_when(
        . == 0 ~ FALSE,
        . %in% 1:2 ~ TRUE
      )
    )
  )
```